# How to select a subset of fields from an array column in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Let say I have a DataFrame as follow :

```
case class SubClass(id:String, size:Int,useless:String)
case class MotherClass(subClasss: Array[SubClass])
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(List(
      MotherClass(Array(
        SubClass("1",1,"thisIsUseless"),
        SubClass("2",2,"thisIsUseless"),
        SubClass("3",3,"thisIsUseless")
      )),
      MotherClass(Array(
        SubClass("4",4,"thisIsUseless"),
        SubClass("5",5,"thisIsUseless")
      ))
    ))
```

The schema is :

```
root
 |-- subClasss: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- size: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- useless: string (nullable = true)
```

I'm looking for a way to select only a subset of fields : `id` and `size` of the array column `subClasss`, but with keeping the nested array structure.
The resulting schema would be :

```
root
     |-- subClasss: array (nullable = true)
     |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- size: integer (nullable = false)
```

I've tried to do a

```
df.select("subClasss.id","subClasss.size")
```

But this splits the array `subClasss` in two arrays :

```
root
 |-- id: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- size: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
```

Is there a way to keep the origin structure and just to eliminate the `useless` field ? Something that would look like :

```
df.select("subClasss.[id,size]")
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Spark >= 2.4**:

It  is possible to use `arrays_zip` with `cast`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.arrays_zip

df.select(arrays_zip(
  $"subClasss.id", $"subClasss.size"
).cast("array<struct<id:string,size:int>>"))
```

where `cast` is required to [rename nested fields](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43004849/) - without it Spark uses automatically generated names `0`, `1`, ... `n`.

**Spark < 2.4**:

You can use an UDF like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

case class Record(id: String, size: Int)

val dropUseless = udf((xs: Seq[Row]) =>  xs.map{
  case Row(id: String, size: Int, _) => Record(id, size)
})

df.select(dropUseless($"subClasss"))
```