# Rename nested field in spark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, rename

Having a dataframe `df` in Spark:

```
 |-- array_field: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- a: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- b: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- c: long (nullable = true)
```

How to rename field `array_field.a` to `array_field.a_renamed`?

[Update]:

`.withColumnRenamed()` does not work with nested fields so I tried this hacky and unsafe method:

```
# First alter the schema:
schema = df.schema
schema['array_field'].dataType.elementType['a'].name = 'a_renamed'

ind = schema['array_field'].dataType.elementType.names.index('a')
schema['array_field'].dataType.elementType.names[ind] = 'a_renamed'

# Then set dataframe's schema with altered schema
df._schema = schema
```

I know that setting a private attribute is not a good practice but I don't know other way to set the schema for df

I think I am on a right track but `df.printSchema()` still shows the old name for `array_field.a`, though `df.schema == schema` is `True`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**Python**

It is not possible to modify a single nested field. You have to recreate a whole structure. In this particular case the simplest solution is to use `cast`.

First a bunch of imports:

```py
from collections import namedtuple
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.types import (
    ArrayType, LongType, StringType, StructField, StructType)
```

and example data:

```py
Record = namedtuple("Record", ["a", "b", "c"])

df = sc.parallelize([([Record("foo", 1, 3)], )]).toDF(["array_field"])
```

Let's confirm that the schema is the same as in your case:

```py
df.printSchema()
```

```
root
 |-- array_field: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- a: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- b: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- c: long (nullable = true)
```

You can define a new schema for example as a string:

```py
str_schema = "array<struct<a_renamed:string,b:bigint,c:bigint>>"

df.select(col("array_field").cast(str_schema)).printSchema()
```

```
root
 |-- array_field: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- a_renamed: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- b: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- c: long (nullable = true)
```

or a `DataType`:

```py
struct_schema = ArrayType(StructType([
    StructField("a_renamed", StringType()),
    StructField("b", LongType()),
    StructField("c", LongType())
]))

 df.select(col("array_field").cast(struct_schema)).printSchema()
```

```
root
 |-- array_field: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- a_renamed: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- b: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- c: long (nullable = true)
```

**Scala**

The same techniques can be used in Scala:

```scala
case class Record(a: String, b: Long, c: Long)

val df = Seq(Tuple1(Seq(Record("foo", 1, 3)))).toDF("array_field")

val strSchema = "array<struct<a_renamed:string,b:bigint,c:bigint>>"

df.select($"array_field".cast(strSchema))
```

or

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val structSchema = ArrayType(StructType(Seq(
    StructField("a_renamed", StringType),
    StructField("b", LongType),
    StructField("c", LongType)
)))

df.select($"array_field".cast(structSchema))
```

**Possible improvements**:

If you use an expressive data manipulation or JSON processing library it could be easier to dump data types to `dict` or JSON string and take it from there for example (Python / [`toolz`](https://github.com/pytoolz/toolz)):

```
from toolz.curried import pipe, assoc_in, update_in, map
from operator import attrgetter

# Update name to "a_updated" if name is "a"
rename_field = update_in(
    keys=["name"], func=lambda x: "a_updated" if x == "a" else x)

updated_schema = pipe(
   #  Get schema of the field as a dict
   df.schema["array_field"].jsonValue(),
   # Update fields with rename
   update_in(
       keys=["type", "elementType", "fields"],
       func=lambda x: pipe(x, map(rename_field), list)),
   # Load schema from dict
   StructField.fromJson,
   # Get data type
   attrgetter("dataType"))

df.select(col("array_field").cast(updated_schema)).printSchema()
```

Comment: Here `str_schema = "array<struct<a_renamed:string,b:bigint,c:bigint>>"` when you know the schema the this works but when I don't know the schema How can we replace all the names with particular string for example `a_renamed, b_renamed, c_renamed` as so on

Comment: @User12345 Spark always "knows" the schema at runtime. If you don't want / cannot hard code `DataType` / DDL string, you have to transform existing schema dynamically. Example of such approach is shown in the last paragraph, but you can find other approaches that will yield the same result.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was trying to have my map function, for example `rdd.map(my_function)` return a structure such as`{"field1": str(row.column1), "field2":float(row.column2), "field3":list(row.column3)}` and spark would be converting the return type to a `map` type and destorying some of the values. Using named tuples I was able to get what I wanted. Thanks :)

Answer (score 15):

You can recurse over the data frame's schema to create a new schema with the required changes.

A schema in PySpark is a StructType which holds a list of StructFields and each StructField can hold some primitve type or another StructType.

This means that we can decide if we want to recurse based on whether the type is a StructType or not.

Below is an annotated sample implementation that shows you how you can implement the above idea.

```py
# Some imports
from pyspark.sql.types import DataType, StructType, ArrayType
from copy import copy

# We take a dataframe and return a new one with required changes
def cleanDataFrame(df: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
    # Returns a new sanitized field name (this function can be anything really)
    def sanitizeFieldName(s: str) -> str:
        return s.replace("-", "_").replace("&", "_").replace("\"", "_")\
            .replace("[", "_").replace("]", "_").replace(".", "_")
    
    # We call this on all fields to create a copy and to perform any 
    # changes we might want to do to the field.
    def sanitizeField(field: StructField) -> StructField:
        field = copy(field)
        field.name = sanitizeFieldName(field.name)
        # We recursively call cleanSchema on all types
        field.dataType = cleanSchema(field.dataType)
        return field
    
    def cleanSchema(dataType: [DataType]) -> [DataType]:
        dataType = copy(dataType)
        # If the type is a StructType we need to recurse otherwise 
        # we can return since we've reached the leaf node
        if isinstance(dataType, StructType):
            # We call our sanitizer for all top level fields
            dataType.fields = [sanitizeField(f) for f in dataType.fields]
        elif isinstance(dataType, ArrayType):
            dataType.elementType = cleanSchema(dataType.elementType)
        return dataType

    # Now since we have the new schema we can create a new DataFrame 
    # by using the old Frame's RDD as data and the new schema as the 
    # schema for the data
    return spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd, cleanSchema(df.schema))
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer! Saved my day. May I suggest to avoid the "import *" and rather use "from pyspark.sql.types import DataType, StructType, ArrayType" - It may be an version issue, but "from pyspark.sql import *" didn't work, since the used Type packages are in subpackage "types"

Comment: Hi Ashhar, this is a great bit of code, thanks for posting it. I am trying to use this on a frame where each row may have a slightly different structure, so using the RDD of the initial DataFrame I think is a problem. I am seeing my structure keys recursively lowercased (my use case), but the values are set to null. Can you shed some light on why that is happening?

Answer (score 1):

I found a much easier way than the one provided by @zero323, along the lines
of  @MaxPY:

**Pyspark 2.4:**

```py
# Get the schema from the dataframe df
schema = df.schema

# Override `fields` with a list of new StructField, equals to the previous but for the names
schema.fields = (list(map(lambda field: 
                          StructField(field.name + "_renamed", field.dataType), schema.fields)))

# Override also `names` with the same mechanism
schema.names = list(map(lambda name: name + "_renamed", table_schema.names))
```

Now `df.schema` will print all the renewed names.

Answer (score 1):

An example of the implementation of an abstract class for fields renaming and a concrete example of it that convert CamelCase fields names to snake_case:

Inspired from the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58030523/7275926

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from copy import deepcopy

from humps import decamelize
from pyspark.sql.dataframe import DataFrame
import pyspark.sql.types as T


class SparkDataframeColumnsRenamer(ABC):

    def __init__(self, df: DataFrame):
        self.df = df

    @abstractmethod
    def rename_field_name(self, field_name: str) -> str:
        pass

    def rename_field(self, field: T.StructField) -> T.StructField:
        field = deepcopy(field)
        field.name = self.rename_field_name(field.name)
        field.dataType = self.schema_renamer(field.dataType)
        return field

    def schema_renamer(self, schema_data: [T.DataType]) -> [T.DataType]:
        schema_data = deepcopy(schema_data)

        if isinstance(schema_data, T.StructType):
            schema_data.fields = [self.rename_field(f) for f in schema_data.fields]
        
        elif isinstance(schema_data, T.ArrayType):
            schema_data.elementType = self.schema_renamer(schema_data.elementType)

        elif isinstance(schema_data, T.MapType):
            if isinstance(schema_data.valueType, T.ArrayType):
                schema_data.valueType = self.schema_renamer(schema_data.valueType)
        
        return schema_data
    
    @property
    def renamed_df(self) -> DataFrame:
        new_schema = self.schema_renamer(self.df.schema)
        return spark.createDataFrame(self.df.rdd, new_schema)


class SnakeCaseDfRenamer(SparkDataframeColumnsRenamer):
    def rename_field_name(self, field_name: str) -> str:
        return decamelize(field_name)


# example of usage
renamer = SnakeCaseDfRenamer(df)
df_with_renmaed_fields = renamer.renamed_df
```

Answer (score 0):

Another much easier solution if it works for you like it works for me is to flatten the structure and then rename:

Using Scala:

```
val df_flat = df.selectExpr("array_field.*")
```

Now the rename works

```
val df_renamed = df_flat.withColumnRenamed("a", "a_renamed")
```

Of course this only works for you if you dont need the hierarchy (although I suppose it can be recreated again if needed)

Answer (score 0):

Using answer provided by **Leo C** in:https://stackoverflow.com/a/55363153/5475506, I have built what I consider a more human-friendly/pythoniac script:

```py
    import pyspark.sql.types as sql_types

    path_table = "<PATH_TO_DATA>"
    table_name = "<TABLE_NAME>"

    def recur_rename(schema: StructType, old_char, new_char):
        schema_new = []
        for struct_field in schema:
            if type(struct_field.dataType)==sql_types.StructType:
                schema_new.append(sql_types.StructField(struct_field.name.replace(old_char, new_char), sql_types.StructType(recur_rename(struct_field.dataType, old_char, new_char)), struct_field.nullable, struct_field.metadata))
            elif type(struct_field.dataType)==sql_types.ArrayType: 
                if type(struct_field.dataType.elementType)==sql_types.StructType:
                    schema_new.append(sql_types.StructField(struct_field.name.replace(old_char, new_char), sql_types.ArrayType(sql_types.StructType(recur_rename(struct_field.dataType.elementType, old_char, new_char)),True), struct_field.nullable, struct_field.metadata)) # Recursive call to loop over all Array elements
                else:
                    schema_new.append(sql_types.StructField(struct_field.name.replace(old_char, new_char), struct_field.dataType.elementType, struct_field.nullable, struct_field.metadata)) # If ArrayType only has one field, it is no sense to use an Array so Array is exploded
            else:
                schema_new.append(sql_types.StructField(struct_field.name.replace(old_char, new_char), struct_field.dataType, struct_field.nullable, struct_field.metadata))
        return schema_new

    def rename_columns(schema: StructType, old_char, new_char):
        return sql_types.StructType(recur_rename(schema, old_char, new_char))

    df = spark.read.format("json").load(path_table) # Read data whose schema has to be changed.
    newSchema = rename_columns(df.schema, ":", "_") # Replace special characters in schema (More special characters not allowed in Spark/Hive meastore: ':', ',', ';')
    df2= spark.read.format("json").schema(newSchema).load(path_table) # Read data with new schema.
```

I consider the code self explanatory (furthermore, it has comments) but what it does is recursively loop over all the fields in the schema, replacing "old_char" by "new_char" in each of them. If field type is a nested one (StructType or ArrayType) new recursive calls are made.

Answer (score 0):

I am curious if there is any reason not to replace the schema as a string:

```
rename_schema=eval(str(schema).replace( "a", "renamed_a"))
df=spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd, rename_schema)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following Python code:

```
s_fields = list(set(df.schema["struct_col_name"].dataType.names) - set(['old_name_nested'])) 
df = df.withColumn(
    'struct_col_name', 
    F.struct(*([F.col('struct_col_name')[c].alias(c) for c in s_fields] + [F.col('struct_col_name')['old_name_nested'].alias('new_name_nested')]))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can create a new field with `withField` then drop the old field:

```
df = (
    df.withColumn("column_with_struct",
        df.column_with_struct.withField('new_field_name',
        f.col("column_with_struct.old_field_name")).dropFields("old_field_name"))
)
```