# create empty array-column of given schema in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Due to the fact that parquet cannt parsists empty arrays, I replaced empty arrays with null before writing a table. Now as I read the table, I want to do the opposite:

I have a DataFrame with the following schema :

```
|-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- arr: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- x: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- y: double (nullable = true)
```

and the following content:

```
+---+-----------+
| id|        arr|
+---+-----------+
|  1|[[1.0,2.0]]|
|  2|       null|
+---+-----------+
```

I'd like to replace the null-array (id=2) with an empty array, i.e.

```
+---+-----------+
| id|        arr|
+---+-----------+
|  1|[[1.0,2.0]]|
|  2|         []|
+---+-----------+
```

I've tried:

```
val arrSchema = df.schema(1).dataType

df
.withColumn("arr",when($"arr".isNull,array().cast(arrSchema)).otherwise($"arr"))
.show()
```

which gives :

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.types.NullType$
>   cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType

Edit : I don't want to "hardcode" any schema of my array column (at least not the schema of the struct) because this can vary from case to case. I can only use the schema information from `df` at runtime

I'm using Spark 2.1 by the way, therefore I cannot use `typedLit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is the use a UDF :

```
val arrSchema = df.schema(1).dataType // ArrayType(StructType(StructField(x,DoubleType,true), StructField(y,DoubleType,true)),true)

val emptyArr = udf(() => Seq.empty[Any],arrSchema)

df
.withColumn("arr",when($"arr".isNull,emptyArr()).otherwise($"arr"))
.show()

+---+-----------+
| id|        arr|
+---+-----------+
|  1|[[1.0,2.0]]|
|  2|         []|
+---+-----------+
```

Answer (score 15):

- *Spark 2.2+ with known external type*

  In general you can use `typedLit` to provide empty arrays.

  ```
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.typedLit

  typedLit(Seq.empty[(Double, Double)])
  ```

  To use specific names for nested objects you can use case classes:

  ```
  case class Item(x: Double, y: Double)

  typedLit(Seq.empty[Item])
  ```

  or [rename by cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43004849/8371915):

  ```
  typedLit(Seq.empty[(Double, Double)])
    .cast("array<struct<x: Double, y: Double>>")
  ```
- *Spark 2.1+ with schema only*

  With schema only you can try:

  ```
  val schema = StructType(Seq(
    StructField("arr", StructType(Seq(
      StructField("x", DoubleType),
      StructField("y", DoubleType)
    )))
  ))

  def arrayOfSchema(schema: StructType) =
    from_json(lit("""{"arr": []}"""), schema)("arr")

  arrayOfSchema(schema).alias("arr")
  ```

  where `schema` can be extracted from the existing `DataFrame` and wrapped with additional `StructType`:

  ```
  StructType(Seq(
    StructField("arr", df.schema("arr").dataType)
  ))
  ```

Comment: is it possible  only use schema-information from df (this would make it more generic)

Comment: actually I found an easier solution using UDF

Comment: @RaphaelRoth Neat.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to use `coalesce`:

```
val df = Seq(
  (Some(1), Some(Array((1.0, 2.0)))),
  (Some(2), None)
).toDF("id", "arr")

df.withColumn("arr", coalesce($"arr", typedLit(Array.empty[(Double, Double)]))).
  show
// +---+-----------+
// | id|        arr|
// +---+-----------+
// |  1|[[1.0,2.0]]|
// |  2|         []|
// +---+-----------+
```

Comment: this also works only for Spark 2.2+ and does need hardcoded type-information

Answer (score 0):

UDF with case class could also be interesting:

```
case class Item(x: Double, y: Double)
val udf_emptyArr = udf(() => Seq[Item]())
df
.withColumn("arr",coalesce($"arr",udf_emptyArr()))
.show()
```