# Rename key in a nested Spark DataFrame Schema (Scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, schema, parquet

I have a use case that needs to read a nested JSON schema and write it back as a `Parquet` (***My schema changes based on the day I am reading the data so I don't know the exact schema in advance***) since in some of my nest keys I have some character like space when I want to save it as parquet I am getting an exception complaining about special character `,;{}()\\n\\t=`

This is a sample Schema it's not real schema keys are dynamic and chages day by day

```
  val nestedSchema = StructType(Seq(
    StructField("event_time", StringType),
    StructField("event_id", StringType),
    StructField("app", StructType(Seq(
      StructField("environment", StringType),
      StructField("name", StringType),
      StructField("type", StructType(Seq(
        StructField("word tier", StringType), ### This cause problem when you save it as Parquet
        StructField("level", StringType)
    ))
 ))))))

val nestedDF = spark.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD[Row], nestedSchema)

myDF.printSchema
```

#### Output

```
root
 |-- event_time: string (nullable = true)
 |-- event_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- app: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- environment: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- type: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- word tier: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- level: string (nullable = true)
```

#### Trying to save as parquet

```
myDF.write
          .mode("overwrite")
          .option("compression", "snappy")
          .parquet("PATH/TO/DESTINATION")
```

I Found some solution like this

```
myDF.toDF(myDF
          .schema
          .fieldNames
          .map(name => "[ ,;{}()\\n\\t=]+".r.replaceAllIn(name, "_")): _*)
.write
              .mode("overwrite")
              .option("compression", "snappy")
              .parquet("PATH/TO/DESTINATION")
```

But it only works on a parent keys, not on a nested one. Is there any recursive solution for this?

My question is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43004849/rename-nested-field-in-spark-dataframe) Since my schema is dynamic and I don't know about what are my keys. It changes based on the data I am reading, so my solution should be generic, I need somehow recursively created the same schema structure but with a key a correct name.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have to construct a `Column` expression which would cast your input to a type with sanitized field names. To do this, you can use the `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.struct` function, which allows you to combine other `Column`s to construct a column of structural type. Something like this should work:

```
  import org.apache.spark.sql.{functions => f}

  def sanitizeName(s: String): String = s.replace(" ", "_")

  def sanitizeFieldNames(st: StructType, context: String => Column): Column = f.struct(
    st.fields.map { sf =>
      val sanitizedName = sanitizeName(sf.name)
      val sanitizedField = sf.dataType match {
        case struct: StructType =>
          val subcontext = context(sf.name)
          sanitizeFieldNames(struct, subcontext(_))
        case _ => context(sf.name)
      }
      sanitizedField.as(sanitizedName)
    }: _*
  )
```

You use it like this:

```
val df: DataFrame = ...

val appFieldType = df.schema("app").asInstanceOf[StructType]  // or otherwise obtain the field type
df.withColumn(
  "app",
  sanitizeFieldNames(appFieldType, df("app")(_))
)
```

For your type, this recursive function would return a column like

```
f.struct(
  df("app")("environment").as("environment"),
  df("app")("name").as("name"),
  f.struct(
    df("app")("type")("word tier").as("word_tier"),
    df("app")("type")("level").as("level")
  ).as("type")
)
```

which then gets assigned to the "app" field, replacing what is present there.

There is a limitation to this solution, though. It does not support nested arrays or maps: if you have a schema with structs inside arrays or maps, this method won't convert any structs inside arrays and maps. That being said, in Spark 2.4 they have added functions which performs operations on collections, so it is possible that in Spark 2.4 this function could be generalized to support nested arrays and maps as well.

Finally, it is possible to do what you want with `mapPartitions`. First, you write a recursive method which sanitizes only the `StructType` of your field:

```
def sanitizeType(dt: DataType): DataType = dt match {
  case st: StructType => ...  // rename fields and invoke recursively
  case at: ArrayType => ...  // invoke recursively
  case mt: MapType => ...  // invoke recursively
  case _ => dt  // simple types do not have anything to sanitize
}
```

Second, you apply a sanitized schema to your dataframe. There are basically two methods to do it: a safe one `mapPartitions` and one which relies on internal Spark API.

With `mapPartitions`, it is simple:

```
df.mapPartitions(identity)(RowEncoder(sanitizeType(df.schema)))
```

Here, we apply a `mapPartitions` operation and explicitly specify the output encoder. Remember that schemas in Spark are not intrinsic to the data: they are always associated with a particular dataframe. All data inside the dataframe is represented as rows with no labels on individual fields, just positions. As long as your schema has exactly the same types on same positions (but with potentially different names), it should work as you expect.

`mapPartitions` does result in several additional nodes in the logical plan. To avoid it, it is possible to construct a `Dataset[Row]` instance directly with a specific encoder:

```
new Dataset[Row](df.sparkSession, df.queryExecution.logical, RowEncoder(sanitizeType(df.schema)))
```

This would avoid unnecessary `mapPartitions` (which, in general, results in a deserialize-map-serialize steps in the query execution plan), but it might be unsafe; I personally did not check it now, but it could work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am a bit lost, in the first step when we apply `sanitizeName` like this `val appFieldType = df.schema("app").asInstanceOf[StructType] ` what's gonna happen to the rest of fields I need to keep the whole schema. and what's `f` in the `sanitizeName` definition.

Comment: and does it preserve the old schema? what's gonna happen to the app added to replaced schema?

Comment: `f` is the `functions` object, my bad - forgot to add an import. In the approach with `f.struct`, I use the `Dataset.withColumn` method, which adds or replaces the specified column with the provided definition (in this case, it replaces the `app` column). Other columns are not affected.