# Rename nested struct columns in a Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, column-alias

I am trying to change the names of a DataFrame columns in scala. I am easily able to change the column names for direct fields but I'm facing difficulty while converting array struct columns.

Below is my DataFrame schema.

```
|-- _VkjLmnVop: string (nullable = true)
|-- _KaTasLop: string (nullable = true)
|-- AbcDef: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- UvwXyz: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _MnoPqrstUv: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _ManDevyIxyz: string (nullable = true)
```

But I need the schema like below

```
|-- vkj_lmn_vop: string (nullable = true)
|-- ka_tas_lop: string (nullable = true)
|-- abc_def: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- uvw_xyz: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- mno_pqrst_uv: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- man_devy_ixyz: string (nullable = true)
```

For Non Struct columns I'm changing column names by below

```
def aliasAllColumns(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  df.select(df.columns.map { c =>
    df.col(c)
      .as(
        c.replaceAll("_", "")
          .replaceAll("([A-Z])", "_$1")
          .toLowerCase
          .replaceFirst("_", ""))
  }: _*)
}
aliasAllColumns(file_data_df).show(1)
```

How I can change Struct column names dynamically?

Comment: do you have the rename columns like Maps(_VkjLmnVop => vkj_lmn_vop, _KaTasLop => ka_tas_lop ) ?.

Comment: @stack0114106, I've plenty of columns. So I'm thinking to change column names dynamically.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create a recursive method to traverse the DataFrame schema for renaming the columns:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

def renameAllCols(schema: StructType, rename: String => String): StructType = {
  def recurRename(schema: StructType): Seq[StructField] = schema.fields.map{
      case StructField(name, dtype: StructType, nullable, meta) =>
        StructField(rename(name), StructType(recurRename(dtype)), nullable, meta)
      case StructField(name, dtype: ArrayType, nullable, meta) if dtype.elementType.isInstanceOf[StructType] =>
        StructField(rename(name), ArrayType(StructType(recurRename(dtype.elementType.asInstanceOf[StructType])), true), nullable, meta)
      case StructField(name, dtype, nullable, meta) =>
        StructField(rename(name), dtype, nullable, meta)
    }
  StructType(recurRename(schema))
}
```

Testing it with the following example:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val renameFcn = (s: String) =>
  s.replace("_", "").replaceAll("([A-Z])", "_$1").toLowerCase.dropWhile(_ == '_')

case class C(A_Bc: Int, D_Ef: Int)

val df = Seq(
  (10, "a", C(1, 2), Seq(C(11, 12), C(13, 14)), Seq(101, 102)),
  (20, "b", C(3, 4), Seq(C(15, 16)), Seq(103))
).toDF("_VkjLmnVop", "_KaTasLop", "AbcDef", "ArrStruct", "ArrInt")

val newDF = spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd, renameAllCols(df.schema, renameFcn))

newDF.printSchema
// root
//  |-- vkj_lmn_vop: integer (nullable = false)
//  |-- ka_tas_lop: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- abc_def: struct (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- a_bc: integer (nullable = false)
//  |    |-- d_ef: integer (nullable = false)
//  |-- arr_struct: array (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
//  |    |    |-- a_bc: integer (nullable = false)
//  |    |    |-- d_ef: integer (nullable = false)
//  |-- arr_int: array (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = false)
```

Comment: Hi Leo , This what I'm looking for. This is really great stuff. Thanks a lot. I'm accepting this answer.

Comment: I don't know how it worked. I've tried but it didn't change nested columns of schema only first level.

Comment: Oh I guess it doesn't work if a column is an array of structures like

Comment: @Dave, thanks for the feedback.  You're right that it didn't cover cases of nested Array elements of StructType.  I've revised the solution to take care of such cases.

Comment: really great way to rename the schema.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, it's not possible to rename nested fields directly.

From one side, you could try moving to a flat object.

However, if you need to keep the structure, you can play with [spark.sql.functions.struct(*cols)](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.struct).

```
Creates a new struct column.
Parameters: cols – list of column names (string) or list of Column expressions
```

You will need to decompose all the schema, generate the aliases that you need and then compose it again using the `struct` function.

It's not the best solution. But it's something :)

Pd: I'm attaching the PySpark doc since it contains a better explanation than the Scala one.

Comment: But I've 10 struct columns having 18 attributes in each struct? Is there any other better approach?

Comment: I would recommend you to code a tail recursive function, that given a schema, it generates all the replace/struct methods.